# JSON parse not working with xml string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json

I have the following line of code at the C#:

```
@{

var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(y));

}
```

And the javascript with error.

```
var x = JSON.parse('@data');
```

Data is like [...]"Value":"\u003croot ex=\"something\"\u003e\u003c/root\u003e" [...]. The original value is a xml string:

```
<root ex="something"></root>
```

My problem is that when I use a xml string at the JSON.parse I got an invalid error: "0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character"

Where is the problem?

Comment: Why did you expect it to work?

Comment: Show us the generated source.

Comment: @AmitJoki Why didn't work? If the value is nota xml string it works

Comment: @Sddf that's what I said. `JSON` is a separate *schema* and has nothing to do with `XML`. Use an `XML `parser instead. `JSON != XML`

Comment: @SLaks The source is "Value":"\u003croot ex=\"something\"\u003e\u003c/root\u003e". I think the problem is with the forward slash.

Comment: That source is not valid xml or JSON. Try running it through a validator service

Comment: @AmitJoki sorry, I want to get the string only, not a xml type.

Comment: What happened to the braces?